# Getting Error Query Selecting too Many row or Filter condition complicated

Tags: apex

I have code which is throwing error sometime back object had less number of fields but now it has more fields. I am getting error on line sObj = DataBase.query(theQuery). Is there any workaround ? Please help.

```
ParentId = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

public pageReference updateQues() 
{

    List<EmailTemplate> emailtemp = [select Id,Subject,Name,HtmlValue,Body,DeveloperName
                      From EmailTemplate where Id=: selTemp];
    If(emailtemp () > 0) 
    {
        htmlQues = emailTemp[0].body;
        htmlQuestion = replaceMerfld(htmlQues,ParentId);
    }
    return null;
}


public static string replaceMerfld(String strContent,Id ObjId)
{
sObject sObej;
String objname = objId.getSobjecttype().getdescribe().getName();
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] r = Schema.describeSobjects(new String[] {objName});
Map<String,Schema.SobjectFields> fields = r[0].fields,getmap();
Id referenceId;
List<String> lstrequiredfields = new List<string> ();
List<Schema.SobjectField> fldObjMapValue = fields.values();
String theQuery = 'Select';
For (Schema.SobjectField s: fldObjMapValue ) 
{
    String theName = s.getDescribe().getName();
    theQuery +=theName+',';

}
//trim last comma
theQuery = theQuery.subString(0,theQuery.length() -1);
theQuery = theQuery + ' FROM ' + ' where Id = ' +'\''+ObjId+ '\'';
sObj = DataBase.query(theQuery);

}
//forming a list of fields in format object.field
for(string f:fields.keySet()) 
{
    schema.DescribeFieldResult describeResult = fields.get(f).getDescribe();
    if(describeresult.isAccessible()) 
    {
    lstrequired.add(objectName+'.'+f);
    }
}
string temp ='';
for (string str : lstrequired ) 
{
    string strLower = str.toLowerCase();
    if(str.split('\\')[1] == 'AMM_Opportunity__c') 
    {
        referenceId = (id)sObj.get((str.split('\\.'))[1]);
        strContent=strContents.replace('{!'+str.split('\\.')[1]+'}','');
    }
    //replacing merge field in contents
    Else if (strContent.containsIgnorecase(str)) 
    {
        temp = strContent.subString(strContent.indexOfignoreCase(str),strContent.indexofIgnoreCase(str)+str.length());
        strContent=strContent.replace('{!'+temp+'}',sobj.get((temp.split('\\.'))[1])+'');
        strcontent=strContent.replace('null','');
        if (strContent.contains('00.00.00','') {strContent=strcontent.replce('00.00.00','');}   
    }
    }
    If (referenceId!=null) 
    {
        strContent=replaceMerfld(strContent,referenceId);
    }
    strContent=strcontent.replaceall('\\{.*?\\}','');
    return strContent;
}
```

Comment: Can you print the query to see if its being generated properly? Also have you added too many formula fields on that object?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal :  Thanks Pranay for help. Yes, I have many formula field also. I tried to follow your suggested code but not working. I have missed some part in my method. Please check the complete method and let me know if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer to your Exception question asked but can be used as a workaround.

As I can see you are trying to populate the merge fields of Email Template using dynamic query.

Starting Winter16, Apex API has released a new method that will do that for you without querrying in database. [Messaging.renderEmailTemplate](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_api_email_messaging_enhancements.htm)

So your replaceMergeFld method will be

```
public static string replaceMerfld(String strContent,Id ObjId)
{
    List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> resList =
            Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(ObjId, ObjId, new List<String>{
                    strContent
            });
    String mergedBody = '';
    System.debug(resList);
    if (resList[0].getSuccess()) {
        mergedBody = resList[0].getMergedBody();
    }
    return mergedBody;
}
```

SRC : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm